# Laravel adding to model

Tags: php, laravel, model

i am attempting to make a select, if the select doesn't exist, create it, and either way, add a timestamp 'last_login'

```
            $user = User::find($auth['acc_id']);

            if (!$user) {
                $user = User::setRawAttributes([
                    'id' => $auth['acc_id'],
                    'username' => $auth['username'],
                    'password' => $auth['password'],
                ]);
            }
            $user->last_login = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());
```

I was expecting that to work, but i guess setRawAttributes is not what im looking for?
Because i dont want to create a new user and then select it to add the last_login

Comment: Have you tried updateOrCreate method ?

Comment: @Dren not sure how that would help me? i do not want to process it at once. I want to create it, edit it and then $user->saveOrFail();

Comment: You want to add a last_login to an existing user right? but if the user with acc_id does not exists you want to create it ? right?

Answer (score 1):

This operation calls `Upsert` Check it in docs:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#upserts

```
$user = User::updateOrCreate([
    'acc_id' => $auth['acc_id'],
    'username' => $auth['username'],
    'password' => $auth['password'],
], [
    'last_login' => date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time()),
]);
```